# What does the X-SourceFiles header do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using a FileStreamResult in ASP.NET MVC 3, I get a response header like

```
X-SourceFiles =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVjdFxqYWNvYlx0ZXN0?=
```

Does anyone know what this header means, and what its purpose is?

Comment: What it means: that's the MIME way of encoding non-ASCII character sets; UTF-8 character set, B for base64 encoded and it decodes to `D:\Project\jacob\test`.  Not sure of purpose.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

The header is understood by certain debugging modules in IIS / IIS Express.  It contains the base64-encoded path to the source file on disk and is used to link a page's generated output back to that source file.  It's only generated for localhost requests, so you don't need to worry about it being displayed to the world when you deploy the application to an actual server.

Comment: To be more specific, this header was added by `WebMatrixSupportModule` if you enable Failed Request Tracing and verify.

Comment: @LexLi I'm seeing the `X-SourceFiles` header added in a WebForms project in VS2017 that doesn't use `WebMatrixSupportModule` at all (no WebMatrix-related DLLs are loaded by my IIS Express process).

Comment: How would it work when run not locally, such as in production?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner `webmatrixsup.dll` is a native DLL (not a .NET one) and it's added to IIS Express via Visual Studio's default `applicationHost.config` file (visible in your SLN's dir at `.vs\$project\config\applicationHost.config`). I looked into it with Ghidra and see that it only adds the `X-Sourcefiles` header when `iisutil2.dll`'s `IsLocalRequest` says so. - but I don't know how `iisutil2.dll!IsLocalRequest` works, sorry.