# Returning an image from an action results in an error in FireBug/Chrome Dev. Tools

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple form that uploads an image to a database. Using a controller action, the image can then be served back (I've hard coded to use jpegs for this code):

```
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        var message = new MessageItem();
        message.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
        image.InputStream.Read(message.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
        this.session.Save(message);
        return this.RedirectToAction("index");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult View(int id)
    {
        var message = this.session.Get<MessageItem>(id);
        return this.File(message.ImageData, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

This works great and *directly* browsing to the image (e.g. `/images/view/1`) *displays* the image correctly. However, I noticed that when FireBug is turned on, I'm greeted with a lovely error:

> Image corrupt or truncated: data:image/jpeg;base64,/f39... (followed by the base64 representation of the image).

Additionally in Chrome developer tools:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg.

I checked the headers that are being returned. The following is an example of the headers sent back to the browser. Nothing looks out of the ordinary (perhaps the Cache-Control?):

```
Cache-Control       private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type        image/jpeg
Server              Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version 3.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles       =?UTF-8?B?(Trimmed...)
X-Powered-By        ASP.NET
Date                Wed, 25 May 2011 23:48:22 GMT
Content-Length      21362
```

Additionally, I thought I'd mention that I'm running this on IIS Express (even tested on Cassini with the same results).

The odd part is that the image *displays* correctly but the consoles are telling me otherwise. Ideally I'd like to not ignore these errors. Finally, to further add to the confusion, when referenced as an image (e.g. `<img src="/images/view/1" />`), no error occurs.

**EDIT**: It is possible to fully reproduce this *without* any of the above actions:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    public FileResult Test()
    {
        // I know this is directly reading from a file, but the whole purpose is
        // to return a *buffer* of a file and not the *path* to the file.
        // This will throw the error in FireBug.
        var buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("PATH_TO_JPEG");
        return this.File(buffer, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you parse the base64 image data in the FireBug error? It would be helpful to know whether that data is identical to your file contents.

Comment: @Marten - That's a good point, I'll try that out later today when I get a chance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all the help. I know this is is going to be a very anti-climatic ending for this problem, but I was able to "resolve" the issue. I tried building my code from another machine using the same browser/firebug versions. Oddly enough, no errors appeared. When I went back to the other machine (cleared *all* cache and even re-installed browser/firebug) it was still getting the error. What's even more weird is that both Chrome/Firefox are now showing the error when I visit *other* websites.

Again, thanks everyone for all their suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming the MIME type is always image/jpeg, and your're not using the MIME type of the uploaded image. I've seen this MIME types posted by different browsers for uploaded images:

- image/gif
- image/jpeg
- image/pjpeg
- image/png
- image/x-png
- image/bmp
- image/tiff

Maybe image/jpeg is not the correct MIME type for the file and the dev tools are giving you a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the thought - but this is not the case because I tried with JPEGs from other websites and JPEGs/PNGs that I created myself.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that the session.Save/Get is truncating the jpeg?

Comment: No because I've written both the input and the output to two separate files and compared with hex editor and they're identical. The data isn't truncated.

Answer (score 2):

Use Fiddler and save this file on the server. Attempt a GET request directly to the image. Then attempt the GET to the action method. Compare fiddler's headers and content (can save out and compare with a trial of BeyondCompare). If they match for both get requests - well.. that wouldn't make sense - something would be different in that case and hopefully point to the issue. Something has to be different - but without seeing the fiddler output its hard to say : )

Comment: Yeah I was going to give Fiddler a try - I'll do that and let you know!

Comment: @Adam - As suspected, the responses are *identical* (except of date -obviously). However, the requests are different where the `<img />` request has `Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5` whereas the direct action method has `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`. You can see for yourself from this link: http://www.mediafire.com/?add7mvu58w11cck. I don't think the request content-types should matter? This really is boggling my mind.

Comment: for giggles, can you setup your route so that a request for action.gif goes to your controller? Im curious if its just a firebug bug when it looks at the extension and expects the above accept headers and in turn gets a gif.

Comment: @Adam - Thanks for the idea - but that didn't work either. This is really frustrating...

Comment: What happened when you tried that? Success in the request? Which headers were successful? As long as the content type is correct and the image bytes are indeed correct you should be fine as per http spec and it would seen to point to faultiness of firebug. I'll try to duplicate.

Comment: @Adam - Setting up a route to point to `/images/edit/24.jpg` and directly accessing it still caused the error.

Comment: On that recent fail - what differs from the successful request (headers?)

Comment: @Adam - The only headers that differs when using `<img />` is the `Accept` header.. which makes sense because of the img tag. However, I used the Modify Headers extension and correctly faked the same header being sent, but the error still persisted. Were you able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 2):

Could it possibly be that the image itself is corrupt?  If you save it as a file on your website and access it directly does the error come up?  How does that request look compared to your action request in Fiddler?  It could be the browsers are trying to get the content type by extension, you could try a route like this to see if there are any changes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "JpegImages",
    "Images/View/{id}.jpg",
    new { controller = "Images", action = "View" }
);
```

One more thing to check.  image.InputStream.Read() returns an integer which is the actual number of bytes read.  It may be that all the bytes aren't able to be read at once, can you record that and throw an error if the numbers don't match?

```
int bytesRead = image.InputStream.Read(message.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
if (bytesRead != image.ContentLength)
    throw new Exception("Invalid length");
```

Comment: See my discussion with Adam in the comments. I uploaded the headers to analyze.

Comment: I dont' see where you mentioned if accessing the file directly instead of through an action differed in any way.  If not, the file is most likely corrupt, maybe caused by the stream.  If they are different, try the route I suggested to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: The file isn't corrupt, see my edit in the OP. I've already tested the action mapped to `images/view/{id}.jpg`, check the comments again. I've also tried placing inside an `<img />` tag which *does* work. But accessing the image directly is what I'm after. Try the action I've posted above.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if it is something to do with X-SourceFiles. I'm doing the exact same thing as you with MVC but I am persisting my byte array in the database. The only difference I don't understand in our headers is the X-SourceFiles.

Here is something about what X-SourceFiles does [What does the X-SourceFiles header do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851684/what-does-the-x-sourcefiles-header-do) and it talks about encoding. So maybe?? The answerer claims this only happens on your local host by the way.

As far as I understand it if you are returning a proper byte array that *is* a jpeg then your code *should* work fine. That is exactly what I'm doing successfully (without an X-SourceFiles header).

Comment: Hmm after reading that, it could be it! I'll try deploying to a non-local IIS and let you know how it goes :).